Power filtering with capacitor
i am constantly struggling to choose the correct value capacitor for power lines filtering/decoupling. I mean how does placing a 1uF caps change the "filtering" instead of a 100nF one, i have understood that high value capacitors theoretically filters out all high frequency noise but in reality over a certain frequency they act like inductor so when need to add smaller caps for higher frequency noise, but how i choose the value/number of those caps? Let's say i have a 100Khz signal that i want to eliminate what capacitor i need tho use?
For example i am now working on a project that utilize 3 laser that need a very stable voltage, that voltage is also used for other thing in the board so i need to have a "filter" for every laser, what capacitor(s) should i use?

Where is this 100kHz noise coming from? How stable is "very stable"? There are more things you can do to mitigate noise than tossing a couple capacitors in there.

Understanding the ESR and ESL of any cap dielectric varies between material and size.
For example, std e-caps** have a \$\tau\$=ESR*C> 100 us typically while "low-ESR" e-caps are typ. 1 to 10 us. Ceramic caps vary from high Dk (X7R) to low Dk (C0G) and will have a much smaller Tau with lower Dk but also lower C so the BW or breakpoint of low ESR extends well below 1us for f>350 kHz.
So you must determine the risetime and thus BW of the spectral noise current and determine the C ratio and ESR ratio from source to decoupling cap to see the ripple attenuation.
More details here and also many other places....
https://web.archive.org/web/20120417090146/http://www.si-list.net/files/published/sun/epep_1998.pdf
**  This means a std e-cap of 10 uF is 10 Ohms or more while a really good low-ESR cap is 1 Ohm, so if your load is 100 Ohms and AC ripple is 1 Ohm you will see very little attenuation of switched ripple current.
ESL depends on the length of the trace and log of Length/Width ratio, so smaller caps will have lower ESL and higher Self Resonant Frequency, SRF. Nominal values are 0.5nF/mm when monolithic and MLCC  layers cancel out.

Let's say i have a 100Khz signal that i want to eliminate what capacitor i need to use?

Let us assume your DCDC converter is the source of this ripple.
What are RdsOn (switch) and DCR of L? Then what is dI/dt= V/L then what is dV/dI= Req? Which is affected by the ESR of caps and Laser incremental Rs when turned on.  The result is complex. Too much DCDC filtering causes voltage lag which causes overshoot on step currents due to reduced gain margin.  If your PSRR is too low, then you need ferrite chokes for external LC filters, but then you must look at the Bode Plots and watch out for spurious SRF resonances from too low ESR+DCR in a series tuned resonance.
What can you do?

Make sure your DCDC converter has current feedback for improved stability.
Check the ESR and DCR of all your components and put on the schematic and run simulations.
Define your specs for ripple and choose better parts to compare ripple and step response and consider 10x or more small ceramic caps instead of 1 large e-cap.


I have never thought of using the capacitor charge formula with the ESR. So basically i have to "think" in rise-time terms, if the noise have rise time higher than the Tau of the cap it will be blocked out, am i correct? Using this method i will also understand if an  impulse will be blocked by looking at its rise time. Thank you.

yes attenuated.

Just check the datasheet/specs of the capacitors and you will easily see the resonance frequency. The resonance frequency is the frequency where the capacitor starts to get inductive.
E.g. use the SimSurfer tool from Murata. In the picture below you can see the frequency characteristic of a 220uF ceramic capacitor.


This detail is available from Murata but never from all OEMs, so you must compute it by estimates of RLC.

The impedance of an ideal capacitor is given by
X = 1 / 2πfC

where f is the frequency and C is the capacitance.  So you want a capacitor that has a very low impedance at the frequency you want to lose.  But as you have found, capacitors also have an effective series resistance (ESR) and wound capacitors have an inductance as well.  The ESR and the inductance will vary between capacitor types, and you's need to look at the manufacturer's data sheet.
In practive a big electrolytic capacitor will shunt the lower frequencies, and a smaller ceramic one will shunt the higher ones.
The impedance of an inductor is given by
X = 2πfL

where L is the inductance.  If you want a more effective filter, you could use an inductor in series with the supply, and then a capacitor across the supply.
